# How can I add an "img" tag to a "p" element in basic Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I'm trying to add an "img" tag inside a "p" element.
However, I can't seem to find how to set the "img" tag attribute.

I have to create this:

```
<p class="titre-recherche"><label>chaîne de caractères saisie</label><img src="croix30.jpg" class="icone-croix"/>value</p>
```

I've tried:
Creating an img element with distinct attributes and appending it to the "p" element:

```
imgp = document.createElement("IMG")
imgp.setAttribute("src", "croix30.jpg")
imgp.setAttribute("class", "icone-croix")
divp.appendChild(imgp)
```

Appending the img directly to the original node (this is ugly):

```
document.getElementById("recherches-stockees").appendChild(divp).appendChild(imgp)
```

Here is my entire section, with comments:

```
var saisie = document.getElementById('zone_saisie').value
// Create "p"
var divp = document.createElement("P")
// set "p" attributes
divp.setAttribute("class", "titre-recherche")
divp.setAttribute("label", "chaîne de caractères saisie")
// divp.setAttribute("img", "src=\"croix30.jpg\" class=\"icone-croix\"")
divp.setAttribute("img", "")
divp.getAttribute("img").setAttribute("src", "croix30.jpg")
.setAttribute("class", "icone-croix")
// Set "p" text
var t = document.createTextNode(saisie)
divp.appendChild(t)
// Create "img"
// imgp = document.createElement("IMG")
// Set "img" attributes
// imgp.setAttribute("src", "croix30.jpg")
// imgp.setAttribute("class", "icone-croix")
// Link "p" and "img"
// divp.appendChild(imgp)
document.getElementById("recherches-stockees").appendChild(divp)
// document.getElementById("recherches-stockees").appendChild(imgp)
```

The final output should be the line given at the start of the post.
Thank you in advance for your help, I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Pete - Sadly, you can't chain like that with teh DOM. That would append `imgp` directly to `#recherches-stockees`. `appendChild` returns the child that was appended, not the parent element you appended it to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ha, learnt something new - how come if you chain it, it only appends the image and not the div?  That is some weird functionality

Comment: @Pete - Because it returns the child that was appended. Since you're passing that into `appendChild` on another element, the child gets *moved* to that other element. I think the idea was you could do `var child = element.appendChild(document.createElement("img")); child.src = "...";` and such. But...yeah, it's not that handy. :-)

Comment: Ah good to know, never knew it returned an element!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` elements are not attributes, which is why using `setAttribute` doesn't work.

Your code here is a correct way to do it:

```
imgp = document.createElement("IMG")
imgp.setAttribute("src", "croix30.jpg")
imgp.setAttribute("class", "icone-croix")
divp.appendChild(imgp)
```

That said, those attributes are *reflected* as properties, so:

```
imgp = document.createElement("IMG")
imgp.src = "croix30.jpg"
imgp.className = "icone-croix" // Note it's className, not class when it's a property
divp.appendChild(imgp)
```

In both cases, you'd do the same thing with the `label` element you want before the `img`.

Alternately, you can use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
divp.insertAdjacentHTML("<label>chaîne de caractères saisie</label><img src='croix30.jpg' class='icone-croix'>")
```

Or since you just created `divp` and it doesn't have anything else in it, you could assign to `innerHTML`.

```
divp.innerHTML = "<label>chaîne de caractères saisie</label><img src='croix30.jpg' class='icone-croix'>"
```

(In all of the above, you still need your `document.getElementById("recherches-stockees").appendChild(divp)` line.)